# Perform action if video freezes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, video, buffer

I'm building a web page that uses custom videos uploaded by user.

I use a `isLoading` state that determine whether the file has been loaded or not.

When the video is small (max 20mb) the video is buffered completely from the beginning and I don't have any trouble playing it, however, if the video is big, let's say 60mb, the network request will only buffer a small portion of the video, and will sart charging the rest of the video while it's played.

The problem with big videos, once it starts playing -thus buffering-, the network is not able to keep up with the playing speed vs the download speed, causing the freeze. Probably my server is too slow.

What I'm wondering if there's a way to check if a video is freezing, and if its, perform something, like stoping the video and showing an alert that internet speed is slow.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (/* video freezes */) {
      /* perform something
      like pause and alert
      user */
    }
  });
```

Tried something like this:

```
if (vidRef.current) {
  // vidRef.current.addEventListener('waiting', (e) => {
  //   console.log('video is waiting!!');
  //   setVidDelay(true);
  // });
  vidRef.current.onwaiting = (e) => (console.log('video is waiting!!'));
}
```

But doesn't do the job, it triggers whenever the video is played.

Also tried using `vidRef.current.currentTime` but even if the video is Freezing, the currentTime keeps counting so it doesn't work.

This is my video embed

```
  <video
    preload='auto'
    ref={vidRef}
    id='video'
    style={{ zIndex: '-1' }}
    onLoadedData={() => setLoading(false)}
    muted
  >
```